# FFmpeg simple 1:1 overlay and concatenate?

Tags: ffmpeg, ubuntu-14.04

I am using ffmpeg on Ubuntu 14.04 (Jon Severinsson's PPA) and am playing video files out of a folder - one by one.

First question I wasn't able to figure out yet - how can I add a simple overlay - 720p footage with 720p overlay (with partial transparency)? So there is no resize or alignment needed - just the 1:1 overlay. I tried a lot already with -vf and -filter_complex but didn't show up.

Second question - with concatenate, is it possible to have the switches between the files seamless? Best without creating a new file - so, on the fly? I need to reduce the gaps between the file switches or eliminate them completely.

This is my bash right now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while :; do
    files=(*)
    ffmpeg -re -i "${files[$RANDOM % ${#files[@]}]}" -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f flv ServerAddress
done
```

So I have everything in /vod - the videofiles, as well as the overlay.png

Thanks a bunch in advance,
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the overlay you need to scale the image to the original source dimensions.

To concat multiple source files that have the same codec use the [concat demuxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate).

Eg:

Make a `playlist.txt` with the following format:

```
file '/path/to/file_1'
file '/path/to/file_2'
file '/path/to/file_3'
[..]
```

And then:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i playlist.txt -i overlay.png -filter_complex "[1:v] scale=1280:720 [ovr];[0:v][ovr] overlay=0:0" ...
```

If the video and the image are the same size you can just use:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i playlist.txt -i overlay.png -filter_complex "[0:v] overlay"
```

**Update**:
Full example:

**You cannot filter and copy the video stream at the same time!**

```
ffmpeg -re -f concat -i playlist.txt -i overlay.png -filter_complex "[0:v] overlay" -c:v h264 -c:a libfdk_aac -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://...
```

If your audio stream is valid and has one of the supported audio rates (44100, 22050, 11025) you can do:

```
ffmpeg -re -f concat -i playlist.txt -i overlay.png -filter_complex "[0:v] overlay" -c:v h264 -c:a copy -f flv rtmp://...
```

Comment: and thanks for your answer. Is this creating a file where all videos are combined, or is it connecting the files on the fly? So there are no more gaps when ffmpeg is switching between them?

Furthermore, I think I need to update to a newer version of ffmpeg. Is it a clean replacement, if I do it like this:

   `sudo ppa-purge ppa:jon-severinsson/ffmpeg
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`


Thanks,
Tim

Comment: If you additionally use `-re` and `-f flv {ServerAddress}` like in your original command it will concatenate it in real-time and send it to the specified server address. I don't know for the ppa, I always compile it.

Comment: Hm, I tried a lot of different setups now and either I get an error, or it doesn't show up on the server. I need the audio and video codec to be copied as well, the overlay 1:1 added and the concatenate on the fly. Could somebody please adjust my command with both, so it actually works? I am close to desperation. :/

Comment: You cannot use filter and copy the video stream at the same time and FLV only supports the 44100, 22050, 11025 audio rates. If your audio stream is valid you can use `-c:a copy` but you cannot copy the video as you need to add the overlay. I updated the answer with a full example.

Comment: Thank you so much, aergistal!! Now it finally works. :) Is there any way to decrease the CPU impact and keep the quality up? I've added simulated CBR, altered the keyframe (40fps -> 2s) and changed the preset/profile. Not sure if this is optimal, maybe you have a better idea to keep the CPU usage low - http://pastebin.com/hHSpHUK2 - Thanks, eC

Comment: In addition to the fast preset you can try a baseline profile for H.264. The compression will not be as efficient though. And please accept the answer :)

Comment: Hey, aergistal! I've encountered problems with recorded files from different systems but with the same settings. After the transisition, there are video artifacts, glitches and framedrops - audio is just fine. Do you have an idea what could be the problem: http://pastebin.com/p73F6wss - thanks a bunch!